# Difference between "Number of messages" and "Message count" in the attribute of address in ActiveMQ-artemis

Tags: activemq-artemis

Environment: Windows or Linux
ActiveMQ-artemis version: any

There are two properties in the attributes of an address. For instance as below. What is the difference between "Message count" and "Number of messages" in the attribute of an address ?

If I want to know how many messages come in the a topic even there is no consumer subscribe it, which one or what else property I should monitor?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in the way `Number of messages` is calculated. It mistakenly counts messages from both "local" and "remote" queue bindings when it should only count messages from "local" queue bindings.

To be clear, "remote" queue bindings represent queues for this address which exist on *other* brokers in the cluster. The address needs to know about these remote queues so it can distribute messages around the cluster properly. They're really just an implementation detail that shouldn't influence the `Number of messages` metric.

I will fix this as part of [ARTEMIS-1964](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-1964).